# AWS Creating RDS instance failed on VPCSecurityGroupIds

Tags: amazon-web-services

Forgive my ignorance, I am new to AWS.

When I attempt to run the following Python code sample, it is returning a failure with when calling the CreateDBInstance with an invalid security group...but the groupId "appears" to be correct...value is correct but it is enclosed in double quotes vs single quotes....but the GroupName is blank. I have confirmed that the security id is correct. What do I need to pass into the VpcSecurityGroupIds to avoid the failure. I have attempted to hardcode both the Group ID and Group Name without success

```
    response = rds_client.create_db_instance(
       DBInstanceIdentifier=rds_identifier,
       DBName=db_name,
       DBInstanceClass='db.t2.micro',
       Engine='mariadb',
       MasterUsername='masteruser',
       MasterUserPassword='mymasterpassw0rd1!',
       VpcSecurityGroupIds=[sg_id_number],
       AllocatedStorage=20,
       Tags=[
       {
          'Key':  'POC-Email',
          'Value': admin_email
       },
       {
          'Key':  'Purpose',
          'Value':  'AWS Developer Study Guide Demo'
       }
       ]
        )
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass the security group ID enclosed in double quotes for example

`VpcSecurityGroupIds=["sg-123456"]`

Answer (score 0):

Refer to: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.create_db_instance

You can run the below code in python 3.7 (your rds instance will be placed in default vpc so you need the sg from default vpc)

```
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    rds_client = boto3.client('rds')
    
    response = rds_client.create_db_instance(
       DBInstanceIdentifier="rds-identifier",
       DBName="db_name",
       DBInstanceClass='db.t2.micro',
       Engine='mariadb',
       MasterUsername='masteruser',
       MasterUserPassword='mymasterpassw0rd1!',
       VpcSecurityGroupIds=['sg-***'], #sg in defautl VPC
       AllocatedStorage=20,
       Tags=[
       {
          'Key':  'POC-Email',
          'Value': "admin_email"
       },
       {
          'Key':  'Purpose',
          'Value':  'AWS Developer Study Guide Demo'
       }
       ]
       )
```